# Spring Autowired in Web Service not working when tested

Tags: java, spring, web-services

I'm trying to configure a web service client like this:

```
@EnableSwagger
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@EnableWebMvc
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

With a second config class for the WS:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"org.myco.myproj.core.endpoints"})
public class WebServiceConfig {

    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() throws Exception {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setContextPath("org.myco.myproj.core.webservices");
        return marshaller;
    }

    @Bean
    public WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
        WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate();
        webServiceTemplate.setMarshaller(marshaller);
        webServiceTemplate.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
        webServiceTemplate.setDefaultUri("http://localhost:11000/ws/");
        return webServiceTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public AccountEndpoint accountEndpoint(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller, WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate) {
        AccountEndpoint client = new AccountEndpoint(webServiceTemplate);
        client.setDefaultUri("http://localhost:11000/ws");
        client.setMarshaller(marshaller);
        client.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
        return client;
    }
}
```

I've generate domain classes from the WSDL using JABX, and created a service endpoint like this:

```
@Service
public class AccountEndpoint extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(String.valueOf(AccountEndpoint.class));

    private WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate;

    public AccountEndpoint(WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate) {
        this.webServiceTemplate = webServiceTemplate;
    }

    public GetAccountResponse getAccount(long accountAgency, long accountNumber) {
        GetAccountRequest request = new GetAccountRequest();
        request.setAccountAgency(accountAgency);
        request.setAccountNumber(accountNumber);

        GetAccountResponse response = (GetAccountResponse)
                webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(request);

        return response;
    }
}
```

I created a simple test to check if this is running, which is returning `NullPointerException` at the autowired field:

```
 @ContextConfiguration("org.myco.myproj.config.WebServiceConfig")
    public class AccountEndpointTest extends TestCase {

        @Autowired
        private AccountEndpoint accountEndpoint;

        public void setUp() throws Exception {
            super.setUp();
        }

        @Test
        public void testGetAccount() throws Exception {

            GetAccountResponse response = accountEndpoint.getAccount(12, 16);

            assertNotNull(response);
        }
    }
```

What I'm missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seem you are missing

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
```

from your test class. Otherwise, you are running with the default JUnit test runner and Spring is not involved.

Comment: Thanks for the input, that was really missing. However, I'm still not able to run the test yet. Is correct to try to autowire a `WebServiceTemplate` object? During debug mode, I notice that my `AccountEndpoint` object has two objects of that class (one I'm creating and one inherited from the `WebServiceGatewaySupport` I supposed). Anyways, in both configs I'm getting a `IllegalArgumentException: 'uri' must not be empty` exception at the `at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive` method.

Comment: @Pedro Sorry, I don't know Spring's WS API. You might want to ask a new question.

Answer (score -1):

Don't declare the variable WebServiceTemplate. Use getWebServiceTemplate(), inherited from WebServiceGatewaySupport, instead.

Comment: Please add a title, as well as any supporting information that you can provide; code error messages, and where the error was encountered.